# Filtering posts for unique titles, only the most recent

Tags: wp-query, sql

I am trying to understand how I can fetch posts for an archive that:

1. Have a unique title
2. Are the most recent version of said unique title

So, if I have 3 posts:

```
title: 'ID1: My Title'
date: 01/01/18

title: 'ID1: My Title'
date: 02/01/18

title: 'ID1: My Title'
date: 03/01/18
```

I would only like to see the last, most recent one returned:

```
title: 'ID1: My Title'
date: 03/01/18
```

This is my current query. I am using the Events Calendar plugin, hence the post_type:

```
$past_events = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => Tribe__Events__Main::POSTTYPE,
    'paged'     => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'eventDisplay'=>'past',
    'orderby'=> 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    's' => $searchText ?: '',
));
```

I'm wondering what to add to this query or if this is something I should try to accomplish with custom SQL? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. However, I am sure there must be a better alternative..

```
$past_events = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => Tribe__Events__Main::POSTTYPE,
    'paged'     => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'eventDisplay'=>'past',
    'orderby'=> 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    's' => $searchText ?: '',
));

$post_arr = array();
foreach ( $past_events as $past_event ) {
    $post_arr[ $past_event->post_title ] = $past_event->ID;
}
```

`$post_arr` will now contain the title of the latest post containing same title as key and the post id as value.